# Unable to add data from admin panel to webpage in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I was trying to add data dynamically from admin to my HTML page in django but when I try to add data in admin panel it is not showing anything in the HTML file. when I do `makemigrations` i am getting this below

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'link' to researchpaper without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option:
```

In admin panel I am getting this error
[image]

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class researchpaper(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    publication = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    authors = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    year = models.DateField("date published")
```

views.py

```
def publications(request):
    data = researchpaper.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'lab/publications.html',context={
       "datas": data 
    })
```

urls.py

```
path('publications', views.publications, name='publications'),
```

HTML file

```
                {% for public in datas %}
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h5>2021</h5>
                        <p style="color: black;"><b>{{public.title}}</b></p>
                        <p style="font-size: 14px;"><i>{{public.publications}}</i></p>
                        <p style="font-size: 14px;"><i>{{public.author}}</i></p>
                    </td>
                    <td><a href="#"
                            target="blank" style="color: dodgerblue;"><i class="ai ai-google-scholar-square ai-2x"
                                style="padding-right: 10px;"></i></a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <hr>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
```

why I am getting this problem please help

snapshot of migrations
[image]

Comment: If you add a new field, it must allow NULL values or have a default value.

Comment: share the model

Comment: I have posted the models code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose the first option and it will appear again, Choose it again and add dummy data like "R", if this doesn't work try to delete all migration file except `__init__` file as well remove `db.sqlite3` file if you use SQLite.

Comment: I have tried what you mentioned but I am getting the same error again?

Comment: Did you delete all files inside `migration` file except `__init__` and removed `db.sqlite3` ? as well `make migration` and `migrate` commands? pls, be sure you made all of these steps, and if you have time add a snapshot from your migration file.

Comment: Thanks, it resolved operational error, but the data added in admin panel is not reflecting in HTML page

Comment: Congratulations! you made a great job. According to data that does not appear in HTML, you can make another question here and add `views.py` file and HTML path to your question.

Comment: Thanks. I have added `views.py` and HTML side in the question please take a look

Comment: Where do you put `lab/publications.html`?

Comment: In templates folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237871/discussion-between-harsh-and-mohamed-hamza).